# How to pass an associative array as a parameter for a stored function?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to pass an array in a stored functionbut it doesn't want to compile and I don't know what I did wrong.

My assiociative array :

```
  TYPE etages IS TABLE OF NUMBER
  INDEX BY pls_integer;
  etage  etages;
  ID  number;
```

My Function header :

```
FUNCTION SHOWRES
 (P_OBJET IN NUMBER
 ,P_DATE_DEBUT IN DATE
 ,P_DATE_FIN IN DATE
 ,PERIODE IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_LIBELLE IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_ENTETE_CAL IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_DETAIL IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_USERID IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_USER IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_SOCIETE IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_COLSPAN IN VARCHAR2
 ,P_INTERVAL_BASE IN NUMBER
 ,P_INTERVAL IN OUT NUMBER
 ,p_reservations IN etages
 ) RETURN BOOLEAN;
```

Comment: `plsql` is PL/SQL - and that's in **Oracle** - but you've tagged your question `sql-server`, which is **Microsoft SQL Server** - that doesn't go together - something is wrong - please fix / clean up your tags!

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer isn't Oracle either; it's a GUI tool for interacting with Oracle. If you are using Oracle, tag [[tag:oracle]].

Comment: It doesn't want to compile ? Well.... maybe if you shared the actual code with the actual error we could have a look and help you solve it ? If you don't want to share the actual code then create a reproducible test example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE etagestyp IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY pls_integer;
  l_etage  etagestyp;
  FUNCTION etagecount (p_etages etagestyp) RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN p_etages.COUNT;
  END;
BEGIN
  l_etage(1) := 100;
  l_etage(2) := 200;
  dbms_output.put_line(etagecount(l_etage));
END;
/

2


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

It's impossible to know what is wrong in your code but this example could guide you in the right direction.

Comment: My error is "Erreur(41,21): PLS-00201: identifier 'ETAGES' must be declared". its the parameter p_reservations that causes the problem.

Comment: If you have defined the type "etages" in a package/procedure you can only reference it from within that procedure (like in my example). If you want to call the function outside of the procedure you need to identify an object type using the "CREATE TYPE " syntax

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment, please update *your question* with a reproducible example. Do not post updates in the comments please